# How to resolve this error while build kernel hook driver using WDK?

Tags: driver, wdk

I try to build the kernel hooking driver using WDK in windows7 x64. I used the code of professional rookit book chapter 3.But I got 2 errors

```
1. c:\chapter03ghost\src\hookmanager.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external sym
bol __imp_KeServiceDescriptorTable

2. c:\chapter03ghost\src\objchk_win7_amd64\amd64\comint32.sys : error LNK1120: 1
unresolved externals
```

Help me!

Comment: Most likely *KeServiceDescriptorTable* isn't addressable anymore with the newer WDK versions.

Comment: I am using WDK 7.0 .How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft decide, KeServiceDescriptorTable is no longer able to been imported in x64 mode, and added PatchGuard technology to protect the SSDT and Shadow SSDT.